# Webservice RESTFUL in Objective C : LINK request

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

Currently I'm working with a web service in my app , and we have Implemented a LINK url to ... link two entities in our database .

But It Seems That It does not work with this kind of request because I don't receive any response When I call the url. (Normally I must receive a boolean with success at true or false with an error message (or not if it's ok).

Any Idea about this type of request ?

My function :

```
-(void)LINKWithNoParameters: (NSString*)path{
    //associate the url api path with the requested path
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[CV_API_URL stringByAppendingString:path]];

//create the request with LINK method & json content
NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[rq setHTTPMethod:@"LINK"];
[rq setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:rq returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

NSLog(@"\n\n-----------------\n Sending this URL in %@: %@ \n-----------------\n\n", rq.HTTPMethod,url);

if ([data length] > 0 && requestError == nil){
    //NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"\n\n-----------------\n RECEIVED DATA : \n-----------------\n\n ");
    [self receivedData:data forRequestComponent:path];
}
else if ([data length] == 0 && requestError == nil)
    NSLog(@"empty reply");
else if (requestError != nil)
    NSLog(@"error : %@", requestError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you used LINK here `[rq setHTTPMethod:@"LINK"];`

try like this

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[CV_API_URL stringByAppendingString:path]];

    //create the request with LINK method & json content
    NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [rq setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:rq returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

    NSLog(@"\n\n-----------------\n Sending this URL in %@: %@ \n-----------------\n\n", rq.HTTPMethod,url);
```

Comment: I don't wan't to use POST I want to use a LINK request.

Comment: use get then  why you want to use LINK

Comment: Because I want to make a relation between two entities in my database and LINK is the best way to do that, but know it works in fact I just forgot to implement the delegate method -didReceivedData, so the data were not displayed